# Magick++ -label equivalent

Tags: imagemagick, pythonmagick

Trying to convert the Image Magick convert command:

```
convert -size 50x50 -background white -fill black -gravity center label:Ryan test.gif
```

to magick++/PythonMagick. Cannot use annotate since I need to have the text auto-sized, which 'label' does. I can do

```
img = PythonMagick.Image('50x50', 'none')
img.backgroundColor('white')
img.fillColor('black')
img.read('label:Ryan')
img.write('test.gif')
```

but img.read does not allow me to specify gravity. Is there a way to do this without using subprocess or os?

Comment: I may be wrong, but as far as I know, `PythonMagick` has not been in active development for years, and `Magick++` refers purely to the C++ **ImageMagick** bindings. If anyone knows better, kindly ping me. I would suggest you consider using `wand` instead http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.9/

Comment: ended up using PIL. Does what I need, but I'll take a look at wand too. Thanks.